# Different font-face for different languages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, css, fonts, font-face

I implemented a site in Umbraco with MVC (Using custom controllers). The client uses Big Noodle Titling in their design manual and requested it used several places on the site as a web-font using @font-face.

As we expanded the site into different languages we ran into a problem with Lithuanian, as some characters are not supported. The plans are also to expand the site to Arabian speaking countries, and i recon we will face worse problems here.

A sample of Big Noodle Titling can be found here (change language to Lithuanian): http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/sentinel/big-noodle-titling/

Now to the question. Is there any way to use a fallback font-face for characters not supported by the language?

Alternatively how do you handle this problem on your international sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I could think of is to add a class to the html element when the language is set to Lithuanian, and apply a new font when this is the case. I think trying to fallback to specific characters would be a pain.

Comment: I also thought of this, but really wonder if this is the generally accepted way to do this.

Comment: I ended up implementing this solution as there where no better ideas out there.